# Classification of finite-dimensional real super C*-algebras

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, division-algebras, super-algebra, real-algebra

The title says it all. I feel like one should be able to find this somewhere, but every time I try to google, I just get results for "super Lie algebras". Does anybody know a reference? I am not so much interested in the proof but rather in the result of the classification.

Physically, finite-dimensional real super C*-algebras should correspond to 1+1 dimensional time-reversal-symmetric fermionic phases. As there are 8 such phases, there should be 8 types of irreducible/simple finite-dimensional real super C*-algebras. But I can't find a place where this is explicitly spelled out.

Bonus: There are 10 real super division algebras, which are also real super C*-algebras I think. I'd guess that those cover all or at least some of the 8 types of real super C*-algebras. So which of the division algebras correspond to which of the types or direct sums of types of *-algebras?

Comment: Did you try to google for Clifford algebras?

Comment: No, good idea! But real Clifford algebras are only special examples of real super C*-algebras, right? Do they cover all types of irreducible blocks?

Comment: Well at least there are 8 real + 2 complex = 10 of them...

Comment: But shouldn't the 2 complex cases be regarded as part of the 8 real cases? As the complex numbers themselves are a real C*-algebra...

Comment: What is a super C*-algebra?

Comment: Just a $Z_2$ graded C*-algebra. Or a super algebra with an anti-unitary involution that changes the order of the product...

Comment: golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2014/07/the_tenfold_way.html

Answer (score 3):

I was looking for this a few years ago, and found it in the appendix of this paper.

El-kaïoum, M. Moutuou. "[Graded Brauer groups of a groupoid with involution](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jfa.2013.12.019)." Journal of Functional Analysis 266.5 (2014): 2689-2739; [arXiv:1202.2057](https://arxiv.org/abs/1202.2057).

Notice the author considers complex C*-algebras with two extra order-two maps that commute, one to give the real structure and one to give the grading.

You can try to extract the result from ``the ten-fold way'' in physics, perhaps from here:

Heinzner, Peter, A. Huckleberry, and Martin R. Zirnbauer. "[Symmetry classes of disordered fermions](https://doi.org/10.1007/s00220-005-1330-9)." Communications in mathematical physics 257.3 (2005): 725-771; [arXiv:math-ph/0411040](https://arxiv.org/abs/math-ph/0411040)

However, the first paper is probably more what you are looking for.